# Invoke-sqlcmd not working when inserting csv data

Tags: powershell

Below mentioned code is generating CSV files successfully, but not inserting into database. Code was working previously, but not now:

Doesn't give error, data is not generating

```
 $DestinationFileName = $DestinationFile
    $SourceFileName = $SourceFile
    $tableNum = $tableNumber
    $DatabaseTable = $DatabaseTableName

     $delimiter = ','
    $objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
    $objWord.Visible = $false # $false
    $objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($SourceFileName,$false,$true)
    $LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item($tableNum)
    $LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
    $LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count

    $RawCSV = for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
        $content= @()
        for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
             $content += ("`"{0}`"" -f $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text -replace "(`r|`n|`t)|$([char]7)?")
        }
        $Content -join $delimiter
    }
    $Csv = $RawCSV | ConvertFrom-Csv
    $objDocument.Close()
    $objWord.Quit()
    # Stop Winword Process
    $rc = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($objWord)
    $Csv
$Csv | Export-Csv $DestinationFileName -NoTypeInformation

$database = 'Test'
$server = '.'
$table = 'ScanDoc'
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "Trun
Import-CSV $DestinationFile -Header Col1, Col2 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object { Invoke-Sqlcmd -Database $database -ServerInstance $server -Query "insert into $table VALUES ('$($SourceFileName)','$($_.Col1)','$($_.Col2)')"}
```

Comment: what i found was above script works fine when run in powershell window. if i execute this powershell script using asp.net it doesnt work. im struggling why this wont run....

Comment: can you explain what's the exact error  ? or how are you trying to do this in asp.net ?